# Finding the probability of two independent random variables Mathematicially

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables each taking the values $-1$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ . Let $Z=XY$. Show that $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent. Are they independent?

Comment: Yes, i tried somewhat but not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could show that the following is true:

1) $P(X=i,Y=j)=P(X=i)P(Y=j)$ for $i=1,-1$ and $j=1,-1$
2) $P(X=i,Z=j)=P(X=i)P(Z=j)$ for $i=1,-1$ and $j=1,-1$
3) $P(Y=i,Z=j)=P(Y=i)P(Z=j)$ for $i=1,-1$ and $j=1,-1$

You will note that those are true so the variables are pairwise independent.

However, note that they are not independent since $\frac{1}{4}=P(X=1,Y=1,Z=1)\neq P(X=1)P(Y=1)P(Z=1)=\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: Could you elaborate the point 1 ,2 and 3 by putting their exact values.